# Nservicebus in production setup

Tags: nservicebus, production-environment

I just came across a business case where Nservicebus would fit really well.
What I can't find is any advice on how to set it up in a production environment. Is it just the choice of profile or are there other things to consider.

The scenario is calling a webservice on the other side of the planet which is pretty slow, so I will need a queue of some sort anyway since there are times when there will be between 1500-2000 requests lined up.

What caveats could I expect setting it up on a Win2008 server standard Ed.

I doubt it's just  plug'n play when it comes to managing security on the server.

/J

Answer (score 0):

NServiceBus sits on top of MSMQ. It is hosted in a generic host container which is out-of-the-box and can run inside any managed process. It really is trivial to set it up.

I am not sure what specific caveats you are asking about. The only difference I can see with a production set-up is things like disaster recovery and monitoring.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wasn't asking for trouble :-), just wanted to know if someone had encountered anything annoying. I've used it on a simple testapp on my laptop. With disaster recovery you mean being able to handle exceptions or??

Comment: Sorry - didn't mean to appear aggressive. What I mean by disaster recovery is high availability setup for resilient to large rolling failures, which is not usually a feature of a development or test environment. Similarly you would not normally set up monitoring in a development environment, but monitoring is crucial in production.